# What is the shortcut key in visual studio for cleaning entire solution?

Tags: visual-studio

What is the shortcut key in visual studio for cleaning entire solution?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't think there is one, by default. My VS2008 certainly has no shortcut defined for the menu item.

Go into Tools -> Customize -> Keyboard... and you will be able to give the Build.CleanSolution action whatever shortcut key you wish!